# Intermediate mySQL Query - join two tables together and limit the results

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my table arrangement:

```
Posts
   post_id
   post_votes

Comments
   comment_id
   post_id
   comment_time
```

I have failed to create a query that does the following:

1. Select 10 **Posts** Order By post_votes desc
2. While getting 5 comments for each post

I will post what I have tried if necessary. 
I am just getting into more complicated queries, any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated

Comment: Since it's PHP, you should nest queries. No need to have use `JOIN` for the task.

Comment: Why would you nest queries in PHP instead of joining?  That seems quite backward.

Comment: I figured I would need to use JOIN, but I am unsure how to get multiple comments for each "Post". Do you know of any good resources for these types of queries?

Comment: group by might be useful  i think

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the "getting 5 comments for each post" part.  MySQL does not handle this very well; to do it right windowed functions are very useful.  MSSQL, Oracle, and PostgreSQL wouldn't have an issue with this.

Comment: This could works ? `select top 10 from Posts as p1 join (select top 5 from Comments where Comments.post_id=p1.post_id) order by post_votes desc` ?

Comment: jerome, will that work on mySQL though?

Comment: I can't say its best solution but I use two approaches for such conditions. First: Get 5 rows for each post using Right join and then in PHP (or any other language) push each row in an array (say $posts) with post id as key. Comments will be another array in $posts. check if(isset($posts[$row['id'])). Second: Do all that stuff in stored procedure, if PHP is not acceptable. As far as I understand, you can't achieve your requirements as pure SQL but I might be wrong.

Comment: @TaylorMac, I think I already used this kind of query with mysql, but not sure at all, you're in better position to test ;)

Comment: I think it should be ok : [correlated subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/correlated-subqueries.html)

Comment: If there are more than 5 comments for a post, which 5 do you want to select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will retrieve 10 post order by desc and also 5 comments order by desc respectively.

```
select post_id,post_votes,comment_id,comment_time,
 @rn := CASE WHEN @prev_post_id = post_id THEN @rn + 1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
        @prev_post_id := post_id from
  (select p.post_id,post_votes,comment_id,comment_time from
  (SELECT post_id,post_votes from posts order by post_votes desc limit 10) p 
   left outer join 
   comments c on p.post_id=c.post_id order by post_id,comment_time desc )m
having rn<=5
```

[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c51b/1) (testing sample of retrieving 3 post order by desc and also 2 comments for each post respectively).

Comment: wow there is much for me to learn about queries. I will test this out, thank you for your time and expertise